# Steps to deploy .NetCore 2.1 application to web server. missing steps

Tags: .net-core, web-deployment

I have built a web app in VS2019 that is a .netcore 2.1 application. It builds and runs fine locally in debug and release mode.
I have bought space from a hosting site on there server and have a registered a domain, they stated that they can run .netcore apps. 
I have deployed the web app to the servers file server, I have used Visual studios publish functionality and used filezilla, my site is in its httpdocs folder which is where there sample html index file was before I deleted them, now in this It has the webroot folder and the dll's here. 
When I look up the website online it shows a 500 error.
I have never set up this type of thing before, am I missing steps, Is there something that I have missed.

Just to note, I have looked up other similar questions regarding this but havent helped.

Comment: make sure that your hosting provider installed the `.Net Core Hosting Bundle 2.1`

Comment: ok I will do, cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming you are trying to host this inside IIS, you need the followings to be installed on the server. [You can download the same from here.](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1). Please make sure you choose the correct hosting bundle for your application. 
   [image]
2. Once that is installed, make sure to open IIS and create an apppool. Make sure you select `No Managed code`.
   [image]
3. Then you can add the web site, and assign the above apppool to the website.

> Hope this helps. Happy coding <3

Comment: no it doesnt but thanks, ive followed this strategy before, thanks though